# SQL Server 2016 Express (Reporting Services) - No Local Server Instances

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, wmi

I am trying to make a local development environment SSRS server (just on my local machine).

I have installed SQL Server 2016 Express with the "Database Engine" and  "Reporting Services - Native" modules.

When I go to "Reporting Services Configuration Manager", I get this initial screen:

[image: Initial Screen]

And then when I hit find (w/ just MY-PC-NAME {Obviously, with my real PC name), I get:

[image: PC Name Only]

And when I add the full SQL Server 2016 Express Reporting Services server instance name (i.e. MY-PC-NAME\SQLEXPRESS), I get:

[image]

I have googled these errors / messages to death and it seems that all of the advice / solutions are for older versions of SQL Server (i.e. 2005 and 2008). I have not really found any information on the WMI Provider (other than: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd353297(v=sql.90).aspx ... of which I tried for v9, v110, and v140) all without success).

- I cannot access the  report server in any way (from IE or IE as
  Admin).
- I have checked and have the SQL Server Reporting Services service
  running.
- I have installed SSRS when installing SQL Server 2016 Express and
  have tried both "Install Only" and "Install & Configure"
  installs...with the same results.
- I have also enabled IIS & Associated Windows Features with no luck
  either.
- I have double checked the Windows Firewall exceptions/rules for SSRS
  and those are correct too.

Has anyone else encountered these errors and fixed them and has a Step-by-step guide to fix these errors / get a local Report Server setup for development purposes?

OR

Perhaps I am going about this process all wrong to get a local Report Server setup for development purposes?

Any advice or insight on this would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: sql express are named instance.. so should be mypc-name\sqlexpress

Comment: I tried that as well (see 2nd picture above) and I get the "WMI Provider Error" of "Invalid Namespace".

Comment: can you post your sql configuiration manager

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Sure, what specific section(s)?

Comment: Could you find a solution? I have exactly the same problem and already checked everything I could google

Answer (score 1):

I had the EXACT same problem. Here's the fix:

1) Go back to the SQL Server download page and re-download the installer for SQL Express.

2) Select the first option to add new features to your installation

[image: Install Step]

3) On the second step of the wizard choose to "add features to your existing instance"

4) When you get to the screen asking which features, choose reporting services

[image: Feature Choices]

5) Complete the remaining steps of the install wizard

6) When you run the reporting services config tool do not put "\SQLExpress" at the end of the service name. When you hit find, "SQLEXPRESS" Will appear below.

Comment: Thanks Dwight! However, when I run the installer and get to the "Features Selection" section, Reporting Services are already selected / grayed out from the initial installation (if that makes sense).